# Word macro that loops through a table and stops at the end

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

I have movie scripts. First column is time code, second column is speaker, third column is dialog.

I want to loop through the entire script, but only doing something to the third column (dialog).

I already have a macro for what I do to the third column. I just need it to:

- start in row 1 column 1
- tab to row 1 column 2
- tab again to row 1 column 3 (then do my pre-built macro)
- then tab again taking me back to r2 c1

But it has to stop when it hits an empty table cell.
My macros keep hitting infinite loops, continuing to create new cells as the tab key is programmatically checked despite many different checks for end of document. All solutions out there assume it is an ordinary, non-tabled document, and code such as:

```
Do Until ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Sel") = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\EndOfDoc")
    '(Do something)
Loop
```

fails.

Comment: Sub looper()

' an example of my failed vba:
With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
Do While .Execute(Forward:=True, Format:=True) = True

        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCell
       Application.Run MacroName:="FixParagraph2"
 
    Loop
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Hi Chris! Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] your post to include additional info. It'd be great if you could check our formatting help and use proper capitalization. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate through rows and cells of a table programmatically without tabbing to each cell:

```
Sub ProcessScriptTable()
  Dim oTbl As Table
  Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

  For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
    Set oCell = oRow.Cells(3)

    'Do something with each cell
    MsgBox oCell.Range.Text
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried @Adam's solution, but it just shows a message box each time it accesses a cell in column 3 without actually performing the steps in my pre-built macro. It doesn't do anything to the cell. Here is the macro as it stands:

  Sub Descriptive_3()
  Dim oTbl As Table

  Set oTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

  For Each oRow In oTbl.Rows
  Set oCell = oRow.Cells(3)

 'prebuilt macro that works as a standalone macro trimming sentences as I need.
  run Application.Run MacroName:="FixParagraph"

  MsgBox oCell.Range.Text
  Next


  End Sub

Comment: @Chris, are you having trouble integrating the existing macro with the above code? If so, please edit your post with your macro and we can help.